# Sencha Touch 2 : Not able to override default css class in custom css file

Tags: css, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I am trying to change the default image in select field with my custom image. Below are the classes declared in sencha-touch-debug.css which needs to be overriden for this change.

```
.x-selectmark-base, .x-field-select .x-component-outer:after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
width: 1em;
height: 1em;
top: 50%;
left: auto;
right: 0.7em;
-webkit-mask-size: 1em;
**-webkit-mask-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAA....');**
margin-top: -0.5em;
}




/* line 634, ../themes/stylesheets/sencha-touch/default/widgets/_form.scss */
.x-field-select .x-component-outer:after {
**background-color: #dddddd;**
}
```

The highlighted red lines are responsible for applying the image and background respectively.

I tried to override these styles in my css class file by declaring them once again in my css class but these 2 highlighted properties are getting the priority anyhow and in spite of giving priority = important in my custom css file, I am not able to override them in my custom css files. Please see, If I comment the highlighted lines in sencha-touch-debug.css then only custom css classes are applied.

My Css class

```
.x-selectmark-base,.x-field-select .x-component-outer:after {
webkit-mask-image: url("../../resources/images/main_menu_arrow.png") !important;
margin-top: -0.5em;

}


.x-field-select .x-component-outer:after {

content: url("../../resources/images/main_menu_arrow.png") !important;
margin-top: -35px !important;
margin-right:8px !important;

}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks
Gendaful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to overcome this issue and applied following stylings to override the default styling by sencha and applied custom image on select field as below.

User Defined CSS >> Applied following styling to override the default sencha style for select field

```
.x-selectmark-base,.x-field-select .x-component-outer:after {

    webkit-mask-image: none !important;
    margin-top: -0.5em;

}

.x-field-select .x-component-outer:after {

    content: none !important;

}

// Applied this user defined class to specify the background color and background image on select field

.chooseCountrySelectField {
        background: url('../../resources/images/main_menu_arrow.png') no-repeat right,  -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #faebb0),
        color-stop(100%, #f3ce72));
}
```

Hope this sollution will be useful to others.